# Why use ')' when calling a function?

Tags: lua

I have the code:

```
function output( string )
   print( string )
end

output 'Hola!' -- Why do I not need `(` and `)` here?
```

When do I not need to use `(` in the `Lua` language.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check [the documentation](http://www.lua.org/pil/5.html):

> If the function has one single argument and this argument is either a literal string or a table constructor, then the parentheses are optional:
>
> ```
>     print "Hello World"          print("Hello World")
>     dofile 'a.lua'               dofile ('a.lua')
>     print [[a multi-line         print([[a multi-line
>      message]]                        message]])
>     f{x=10, y=20}                f({x=10, y=20})
>     type{}                       type({})
> ```